# Woo Boutique Theme Category Price Banner - change

Tags: woocommerce, themes, banner, price

I am using Woocommerce - Boutique theme.

This theme has a price banner on the category pages that I have wrestling with.  In the standard theme, it is on the top of the product image, and semi blocks the image, so I moved it to the bottom of the product image, and with in-between screen sizes, it now blocks the category product name text below the image.  In mobile view, the price banner moves way to the right.

I would love it if I could get the price banner to behave,and stay with the product image and not block anything or move, but failing that, I would like to just have the price as plain text below the product and product title - so that it looks the same on any size screen - if anyone can perhaps take a look and see how I can accomplish this - I am at a loss.

Months ago in the Boutique forum I was given the below solution - but it did not do anything to change the banner for me - it didnt change anything..

```
    span.price {
    color: black;
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: none;
}
span.price:after {
    display: none;
}
```

The site I need help with is [here](https://dogshoppe.net/product-category/dog-breeds/beagle/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

/* REMOVE PRICE BANNER MEDIA ALL*/

```
ul.products li.product .price {
position: relative;
top: .01em;
padding: .1253em .3857em;
background: none;
color: black;
box-shadow: none;
font-weight: 400;
}
ul.products li.product .price:after {
display: none;  
}
```